# How to see that this function is onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and denote by $\textbf{R}^X$ the set of all functions $f: X \to \textbf{R}$. I know that $\textbf{R}^X$ is a vector space under the operations$$(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x),\text{ and }(r \cdot f)(x) = r \cdot f(x)$$ My question is, how can I see that for $X$ being the finite set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ the space above is isomorphic to $\textbf{R}^n$?

Let

$$\Phi: \Bbb R^X\to \Bbb R^n,\; f\mapsto (f(1),\ldots,f(n))$$
then we have
$$\Phi(\alpha f+g)=\alpha\Phi(f)+\Phi(g)$$
and that $\Phi$ is bijective.

My question is, how do we know that this function $\Phi$ is onto?

Comment: What do the points in $\mathbb R^n$ look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every point in $\mathbb R^n$ is a tuple of the form $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. Define $f$ to be $f(i) = x_i$. Such a function exists for each point of $\mathbb R^n$ and so $\Phi$ is surjective.